# Session values are not available in safari browser

Tags: java, jsp, safari

*In Safari browser preferences -> Cookies and website data -> Allow from websites I visit (option i have chosen)*

**I have fired my domain url , then I have stored some values in session (jsp file) and after login page come, user entered username and password then click the submit button, internally I have submitted the form to another jsp file but their session values are clearing( if the request coming from one jsp to another jsp the session values are clearing).**

Please help how to resolve this, if you have any queries please ask me

Comment: Please post code

Comment: Are u forwarding or redirecting?